# How to get the area of an image in WPF that is bounded inside a rectangle as a separate image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

With the help of this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753590/using-a-rectangle-to-create-a-search-region-on-an-image) I created a simple WPF application where the user can define a specific rectangle area inside an image with the mouse. What I need to do is to get as a separate image (to save it, or for other tasks) the area that is bounded inside this rectangle. I have tried this with the help of RenderTargetBitmap, but with no success so far because this method accepts only the width and height of the bitmap to be saved and not the top left Point of the desired area. (below there is a sample of code and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdHVY.png) is a sample image of the desired result).
Any ideas of how to do this would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance...

```
System.Windows.Rect rect = new Rect(
    x: topLeftPoint.X,
    y: topLeftPoint.Y,
    width: rectangle.Width,
    height: rectangle.Height);

RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    pixelWidth: (int)(rect.Right - rect.Left),
    pixelHeight: (int)(rect.Bottom - rect.Top),
    dpiX: 96d,
    dpiY: 96d,
    pixelFormat: System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(imgSampleImage);

BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
pngEncoder.Save(ms);
ms.Close();

File.WriteAllBytes(@"F:\Pictures\TEST\test.png", ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: Try CroppedBitmap.

Comment: @Clemens thank you very much for your reply, I had already tried CroppedBitmap, before posting this question, with wrong result. Probably I used it in a wrong way. However, I had a eureka moment a few hours ago and after making some corrections in the code I managed to find the solution. So, I will post an answer  to my question in order to assist anyone else who may have a similar problem.